# Can JGroups be configured to support work queues?

Tags: jgroups

I'm looking for a distributed, reliable work queue.  Where remote processes can take units of work from the queue when they are free.

I'm dealing with a distribution of quite heavy-weight tasks, where consumer microservices can only take one task at a time.

I've seen in examples that JGroups can provide reliable round robin message distribution.  But I haven't managed to find any examples where the *consumer* can choose when to take a task.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JGroups used to have a ReplicatedQueue, but I removed it some time ago. The reason was that I didn't like the semantics it provided: without total order (SEQUENCER), replicas could get out of sync. Also, network partitions were not handled in a meaningful way.

Besides, JGroups is more about reliable messaging and cluster management, and I didn't want to focus on building blocks too much.

However, it should be quite simple to create a replicated queue on top of jgroups-raft [1].

[1] https://github.com/belaban/jgroups-raft